# Need help on how to use Frontend file upload plugin by netsti in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, upload, octobercms

I am trying to use [NETSTI Frontend File Upload Plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/netsti-uploader) but have no luck setting it up yet. After download I created a page, dragged and dropped the component where I want it, set up my model and key column to `allimage` from

```php
public $attachMany = [
    "allimage" => "System\Models\File"
];
```

but keep getting the error:

> Call to a member function allimage() on null
>   Please how can i fix this

Comment: Whayt is NETsti file upload? Could you provide a link to the code?

Comment: I have updated that

Comment: I don't see anything on your code similar to the code provided on the documentation section from the link.

Comment: the information you have provide is not enough. Can you also post how you have implemented on component class?

Answer (score 0):

have you seen that part in plugin documentation?

[image]

you need set **deferredBinding = "1"** in plugin properties and it will work.

Comment: I already have a model for it and i added it to the component. That is where ``public $attachMany = [
    "allimage" => "System\Models\File"
];`` came from. I have this in place 
``[imageUploader]
placeholderText = "Click or drag images to upload"
maxSize = 5
fileTypes = ".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
imageWidth = 100
imageHeight = 100
imageMode = "crop"
modelClass = "Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Advert"
modelKeyColumn = "allimage"
identifierValue = "{{ :id }}"
deferredBinding = 0``

Comment: but you need to set deferredBinding = "1".  right it is deferredBinding = 0

Comment: changing deferred to 1 showed but not working. I tried it the component way exactly like in the documentation but getting _Class name is not registered for the component "Responsiv\Uploader\Components\ImageUploader". Check the component plugin._ error